# Issue opening connection to website using rvest

Tags: r, rvest, httr

There is a url I can open without problem in a Chrome browser but it is unavailable using rvest

```
library(rvest)

u <- "https://github.com/issues?q=is%3Aissue+author%3Atimelyportfolio+is%3Aopen"

dom <-read_html(u)
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404


library(httr)

http_status(u)
Error in UseMethod("status_code") : 
  no applicable method for 'status_code' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Help Appreciated

Comment: Pretty sure it requires a valid, logged-in session

Comment: The gh package enables access to the Github API and proved a more successful route